# JavaScript CSS - Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello I need help with my menu if it shows more than 10 on dropdown menu in my exaple below.I want that when  I click on ... button (see in example) show the other six languages. I am not good at javascript. Here is the example of the menu where ... is I want on click to show the other Language.

HTML code

```
<li>
    <div class="buttonbg gradient_button"><a href="Browse" target="_self">Language</a></div>
    <ul class="gradient_menu">
        <li class="gradient_menuitem first"><a href="Arabic" target="_self" title="">Arabic</a></li>
        <li class="gradient_menuitem"><a href="Brazilian" target="_self" title="">Brazilian</a></li>
        <li class="gradient_menuitem"><a href="Dutch" target="_self" title="">Dutch</a></li>
        <li class="gradient_menuitem"><a href="English" target="_self" title="">English</a></li>
        <li class="gradient_menuitem"><a href="French" target="_self" title="">French</a></li>
        <li class="gradient_menuitem"><a href="German" target="_self" title="">German</a></li>
        <li class="gradient_menuitem"><a href="Greek" target="_self" title="">Greek</a></li>
        <li class="gradient_menuitem"><a href="Indonesian" target="_self" title="">Indonesian</a></li>
        <li class="gradient_menuitem"><a href="Malay" target="_self" title="">Malay</a></li>
        <li class="gradient_menuitem"><a href="Norwegian" target="_self" title="">...</a></li>
        <li class="gradient_menuitem"><a href="Romanian" target="_self" title="">Romanian</a></li>
        <li class="gradient_menuitem"><a href="Spanish" target="_self" title="">Spanish</a></li>
        <li class="gradient_menuitem"><a href="Swedish" target="_self" title="">Swedish</a></li>
        <li class="gradient_menuitem"><a href="Thai" target="_self" title="">Thai</a></li>
        <li class="gradient_menuitem"><a href="Turkish" target="_self" title="">Turkish</a></li>
        <li class="gradient_menuitem last"><a href="Vietnamese" target="_self" title="">Vietnamese</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Example url with css
http://jsfiddle.net/6pxaE/10/

Or with javascript example and all menu show the example that's I want to be the ...
http://myseacheck.besaba.com/ScrollDown.htm

Comment: r u looking like this? http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/6pxaE/11/

Comment: Which other 6 languages?

Comment: +Susesh Ponnukalai Yeap but I want to display it better..and on click to undisplay again

Answer (score 1):

Try this js:

```
$(".gradient_menuitem:gt(9)").css("display","none");
$(".gradient_menuitem:eq(9)").click ( function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $(".gradient_menuitem:gt(9)").css("display","block");                        
 });
```

/* update */

```
$("#mbmcpebul_table").hover( function () {
 $(".gradient_menuitem:gt(9)").css("display","none");
});
```

[**Updated DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6pxaE/16/)

Comment: Hehe nice but when they click it again make it unvisible...and set time to display better ;p thanks :D

Comment: @OnlyHDMovies : Is that fine ?

Comment: If they click ... again the displayed will be undisplayed..but ok its nice if you can do that see the last example I have on the web..and see how its scrolling the Example with time..if you can do it like that you will be awesome thanks anyway :D

Comment: No before it was better ;/ I want the ... showing and on click goes last...but anyway if you cant help me more I will try to find it alone

Comment: Yeah and on click the ... I want to go last ;p I want to display like...when they pressed I will add time so it will display awesome and it will go at last with a button witch is like the 2nd example

Comment: @jeekonline come on help me...I want to make last one and on click to set time so it will display better

Comment: Yeap :D You are amazing ^^ But on click to go back ;p and please set time on it to display better ;/

Comment: @OnlyHDMovies : It's simple and can be done by css transition! Please go through code of your CSS and have a try ... ;p

Comment: @jeekonline come on ;p I have to do and more ;/ Help me out its easy for you :( Set time and make it go back please

Comment: @jeekonline Please just this ;/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".gradient_menuitem:gt(9)").css("display","none");

$(".gradient_menuitem:eq(9)").click ( function (e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  $(".gradient_menuitem:gt(9)").css("display","block");       
  $(".gradient_menuitem:eq(9)").hide();

});


$(".gradient_menu").mouseleave(function(){
   $(".gradient_menuitem:gt(9)").hide();       
   $(".gradient_menuitem:eq(9)").show();
});
```

Use this jQuery, it works fine for me.

Here is a **[Fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nrsantharam/6pxaE/18/)**